# How can I prepare for an interview over TeamViewer and Skype?

Tags: interview

I am in big dilemma what to do or not... Tomorrow have an interview on [TeamViewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamViewer) and Skype for a web developer position in PHP.

They want to take my technical interview there, so I think they will give give me a PHP program to write. The thing is that PHP has vast variety of functions so its not possible to keep all the functions in mind or on finger tips: Google is really needed.

I am aware about how to solve problems, but it may be the case that I don't know the exact syntax for questions they ask.

So what  should I do in this case? How can I convince them that I know how this can be accomplished but the exact syntax is not coming immediately to mind?

Also, what type of question might they ask?

*Some thing about me so that may be you can give your advice accordingly*

Am a junior web developer who has 14 month experience in PHP.
My skills : PHP, Mysql, Magento, Wordpress, CSS, HTML, Javascript...

Comment: Well, programmers are not paid for remembering every single function there is. PHP.net is a great resource for a reason. If they don't hire you just because you use PHP.net and Google, they're stupid. Where I work, using Google in on-site interviews IS what we want, in case you don't use it and spend half of your time re-inventing some stupid algorithm, your problem :O

Comment: Yeah... I agree... Thats why I just want how can I convince them in Polite way... Please help if you can

Comment: Well, tell them that you're focusing on the big picture. Not on tiny little problems which have been solved thousands of times before. So they don't want you to waste your time on that stuff, but rather to work on the actual functionality of their awesome new product. If they don't understand it, you can't do anything about it. In the end it might just as well be that they don't care about you using Google etc. :)

Comment: make it explicit; in other words do not try to hide that you're (at some particular moment) "just looking for a definition of that_function(...) at ... that site..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are being interviewed by programmers, then they will know what the process of programming looks like.

They will expect that certain parts of PHP come to you instantly, based on your experience, and if you are checking the docs to see how to write a for loop or define a function, you will not be hired.  You should definitely be able to code [FizzBuzz](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html) without hesitation or reference.

And they will expect that the details of date formats and file I/O will not always be at your fingertips, but that you have enough experience to know where to look, to find the answer quickly.

If internet is allowed and you come to such a situation, go directly to the official documentation (do not google or stackoverflow, unless absolutely necessary). If they are not allowing any internet, explain that you forget the exact syntax, tell them your best guess, and tell them where you would look for the answer.

If those interviewing you have so little concept of programming that their hiring is based on memorization of obscure API functions, then you don't want to work for them anyway.

Comment: +1 for "... then you don't want to work for them anyway" It is far more important to *think* like a programmer. In an interview in 1978 at Xerox I was asked a question about string hashing. I didn't have any experience with hashes and said so. He gave me a quick explanation and then asked me to wing it, which I did for the next 45 minutes. He later told me that I got the job because in that short period of time I had "independently discovered" several of the problems associated with hashing collisions and even came up with a semi-novel way of solving one of them. It was a great job.

Comment: Also, fall back to [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) if you don't remember the syntax. It would still show them *how you think*.

Comment: An alternative to quietly switching tabs is to ask "I know I haveto use this function but am unsure about parameter order" or 2i now thereis a string function for that, but I don't have the exact name", talking helps the interviewer more and maybe they can help faster than google/php.net